# How to exec http GET/POST requests in several methods (one method for every request type)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code simple http server using python3. I want to exec different methods for every request type. For example, when i use url

```
http://localhost:8080/methodA?p1=v1&p2=v2
```

then i want to exec method

```
def methodA:
    pass
    ....
```

when i use `methodB` in URL, then i want to run method `methodB` in code, etc..

How to implement this in `do_GET` or `do_POST` methods?

edit: thats my current sample code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import urllib.parse

class oraHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def methodA(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('methodA'.encode('utf-8'))
        return

    def methodB(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('methodB'.encode('utf-8'))
        return

    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)
        if parsed_path.path.endswith('/methodA'):
            self.methodA()
        elif parsed_path.path.endswith('/methodB'):
            self.methodB()
        else:
            self.send_error(501)
        return

def run():
  print('http server is starting...')
  server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
  httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, oraHTTPRequestHandler)
  print('http server is running...')
  httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

Comment: Unless you are doing this for amusement/education, take a look at something like bottle or flask.

Comment: I agree with mhawke. however if you are doing this as a learning exercise then please try to implement your `do_GET` and `do_POST` methods - i.e. write as much code as you can and ask a new question (showing your code) when you can go no further.

Comment: Make sure you inspect the header of the incoming message.